# OOP Hello World in Java

Tags: java, oop

This is My 1st OOP app
I Import all the bellow things but When I try to call a class of try01 package It didn't Work. Can anyone guide me to do this thing correctly?

```
package try01;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Comment: Well firstly, where is `panelMain` even defined? Second, what is the actual error this causes?

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you are doing, better not edit the parts the IDE controls.  Saves you some trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *it didn't run* If you are seeing any error message, please quote in the question, please, it can tell us a whole lot. Quote: “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include … a specific problem or error … in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.” From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you are trying to learn OOP, stay away from Swing. It's more likely a distraction for you especially at the beginning. I am only speaking for myself here, but I honestly don't remember when was the last time I had to do Swing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class with `Try01.class`, so the compiler won't be able to identify `new try01()` here `Frame.setContentPane(new Try01().panelMain);`
Also, the panelMain is not defined.

Change it to this - `Frame.setContentPane(new try001());`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

your code has a compile error, if you only change the line above it will be ok.

Change -> Frame.setContentPane(new Try01().panelMain);

To -> Frame.setContentPane(Frame.getContentPane());

The class Try01() didnt exists, this is because your code didnt build.